# What is Goldline? Is it a paper? A manufacturer?

Tags: paper

I often see/have owned sketchbooks from various brands that are described as 'Goldline'. What is Goldline? Is it a type of paper? A specific weight? A manufacturer?

Comment: Can you give the names of those brands? I know there is a line of products by the French paper company Clairefontaine called Goldline, but I doubt the name refers to a material or material quality.

Comment: I think then, that's it. I'll have to dig out my old sketchbooks but the one on my desk is a Clairefontaine one. I know I've owned a few that had Goldline written across the front. The Clairefontaine brand mark is probably less prominent on those ones.

Comment: Yes, some might even completely lack the Clairefontaine logo (but maybe mention the brand by name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goldline is a registered trademark and brand name of ExaClair, a company that owns a number of more commonly known brands in the general areas of paper, fine arts supplies, office supplies, etc.  The Goldline trademark is applied to a range of products from various companies under the ExaClair umbrella, like Clairefontaine and Exacompta.